# ¿Cuál es el origen de "ropavieja"?

Tags: etimología, modismos, expresiones, comida

En el Diccionario de la Lengua aparece [**Ropa vieja**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WhTo2TW) dentro del artículo "Ropa" como

> 1. f. Guisado de la carne y otros restos que han sobrado de la olla.

y
[**Ropavieja**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WhW6HVA) como artículo aparte:

> 1. f. Cuba y Méx. Plato de la cocina criolla que se hace con carne de res cocida y luego deshilachada y sazonada con tomate y otros condimentos que se agregan al freírla ligeramente.

mientras que en [**Wikipedia**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ropa_vieja) se da una descripción más amplia:

> La **ropa vieja**, **carne desmechada**, **carne desmenuzada** o **carne mechada** es una preparación a base de carne deshebrada, específicamente de la falda de la vaca, consumida sobre todo en la Comunidad de Madrid, la Región de Murcia, Andalucía, las Islas Canarias, Cuba, Venezuela, Puerto Rico, Colombia, México, Costa Rica y Panamá. Existen muchas formas de preparar el plato, pues suele ser un plato derivado.

para luego detallar las diferentes variantes dentro y fuera de España.

La cuestión es ¿de dónde le viene el nombre de **ropa vieja** o **ropavieja**? ¿Cómo se estableció esta curiosa relación entre la ropa y la carne?

Comment: ¡Buena pregunta! Siento curiosidad por conocer la respuesta...

Comment: Aparece ya en el RAE de 1803 como "El cocido u olla cocida, y frito después en sartén."

Comment: Ayer fui a cenar con una amiga a un restaurante libanés y tenían ropavieja. Pues le comenté a mi amiga libanesa que en mi país, Cuba, le decimos ropavieja y le expliqué la definición y ella me dijo que en árabe a las cosas usadas, como la carne que se usa para la ropavieja ya que esta se usó previamente para sopa o caldo, le dicen "robabikia". (OMG so many words alike!) Le estaba contando a esta amiga que necesito comprar la alacena para la cocina de mi piso y ella me dijo que en árabe formal se dice "alhacena" — ¡Ahhhh! ¡¡Muchas costumbres y palabras compartimos!!

Answer (score 3):

Propongo un par de opciones:

- Por un lado, se podría pensar en que la comida es de reaprovechamiento y que por ahí le vendría en nombre. En el diccionario de Covarrubias de 1611, y posteriormente en los diccionarios de la RAE, se define el término "ropavejería" como "las tiendas donde se venden vestidos viejos, o ropas". Es decir, que era común darle a la ropa usada una segunda oportunidad, tras haber sido reacondicionada para su uso (Covarrubias decía "el que vende ropas raídas y renovadas").
  El símil entonces quedaría claro, si tenemos en cuenta que la "ropa vieja" consiste en darle a las sobras una segunda oportunidad, tras volverlas a guisar y preparar para una segunda comida.
- Por otro lado, según se comenta en [este blog](http://www.enciclopediadegastronomia.es/recetas/carnes/vacuno/ropa-vieja.html), el origen tendría más bien que ver con la pinta del plato:

  > [...] es un plato de origen sefardí, y en ese idioma se llamaban "handrajos", o sea, andrajos en castellano, lo que viene a ser lo mismo que "ropa vieja" aunque aún más gráfico, porque el aspecto que ofrece esta carne es realmente ese, de jirones, guiñapos, desgarrones, harapos, trapos rasgados.

La verdad es que esta segunda propuesta parece más plausible.

Comment: Tu segunda propuesta me parece una buena teoría, en mi casa siempre se cuenta que mi tía llamaba a la sopa de ajo "sopa de trapos" por el aspecto de trozos de tela que tiene el pan mojado. Conocía la _ropa vieja_ de Canarias aunque hay recetas por todo el mundo pero no sabía que "andrajos" era otro plato al que llaman también harapos, jarapos, guiñapos o tallarines y tiene toda la pinta de tener esos nombres por su aspecto